# Where to put my ARM templates for Azure Function App projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-functions-core-tools

I've got some Azure Function Apps that I've created using the Azure Functions template in Visual Studio (i.e. the [Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioWebandAzureTools.AzureFunctionsandWebJobsTools) Visual Studio extensions).

This works great and I can deploy my Function Apps to my personal Azure subscription, however, I don't want to use Visual Studio to create and deploy Function Apps to work subscriptions. Ideally we use ARM templates to create the Function App Services and use package/zip deployments of the code via the command line through CI/CD.

Where do people put the ARM templates? I was thinking of creating a separate project in Visual Studio using the Azure Resource Group template, but this means I'd have 2 projects for each Function App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you either have a centralized Infrastructure as Code (IaC) repo (or maybe several of these) and store IaC code in there or you store it along side the application code in the same repo just have a IaC folder somewhere. It really depends, with the centralized approach you can have code reuse\centralized management, so I tend to think its better

Comment: I think this is the right approach. We use Ansible so ARM template could live in the Ansible repo.